# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'wings' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsp, view, jsp-tags, mode

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password, Model model,
            HttpSession session) {
        boolean isValid = sodao.login(email, password);
        if (isValid) {
            String role = sodao.findRole(email);
            session.setAttribute("user", email);
            session.setAttribute("role", role);
            if (role != null) {
                if (role.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
                    List<String> list = sodao.getWingsList();
                model.addAttribute("wings", list);
                    return "home";
                }
                else {
                    return "member";
                }
            }
        }



public List<String> getWingsList() {
        List<String> list = template.query("select * from wings", new RowMapper<String>() {

            @Override
            public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
                String me = (rs.getString("wingName"));
                
                return me; // When debug getting my wingslist name;
            }

        });
        return list;
```

jstl added

```
<c:forEach items="${wings}" var="w">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" <c:out value="${w.wings}" />></button>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `w` is list element of String type, so use `w` only.

```
<c:out value="${w}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "wings" is a List of String, therefore the variable "w" will be a string.

The line `<c:out value="${w.wings}" />` should be replaced by `<c:out value="${w} />`